# NullPointerException while accessing SQLite from non-activity class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

While accessing **SQLite** from **non-activity class**, getting `NullPointerException`

File -> `SessionDB.java`

```
public class SessionDB {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private SQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { SQLiteHelper.SESSION_ID,
  SQLiteHelper.SESSION_STRING };

public SessionDB(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void createSession(String session_string) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLiteHelper.SESSION_STRING, session_string);
    database.insert(SQLiteHelper.SESSION_TABLE, null, values); // NullPointerException Here
}
}
```

File ->`Live.java`

```
public class Live {
    protected Context context;

    public Live(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public accessOK {
        SessionDB ses = new SessionDB(context);
        ses.createSession("Sample"); // NullPointerException
    }

}
```

Then, what should be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be calling SessionDB.open() anywhere. This means that your database field is never being initialized, so is null when you call SessionDB.createSession().

Comment: this should be added as a comment. not an answer

Comment: Fine, I've rephrased it as a statement.

Comment: even now this should be added as a comment. Not enough details to post it as an answer. Add bit more details or some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I added one line to the topic starter's code. Now it should work. Check it please.

```
public class Live {
    protected Context context;

    public Live(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public accessOK {
        SessionDB ses = new SessionDB(context);
        // You have missed call to open method here:
        ses.open();
        ses.createSession("Sample"); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File -> SessionDB.java should extend SQLiteOpenHelper

i have modified the code

```
public class SessionDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SESSION_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "SESSION_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "SESSION_STRING";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "session.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_1 + " integer primary key autoincrement," + COLUMN_2
        + " text);";

    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);     

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    /*
     * Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
     * "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
     * + ", which will destroy all old data");
     */
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);       
    onCreate(db);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
    database.close();
    }

    public void createSession(String session_string) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_2, session_string);
            database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

File ->Live.java

```
public class Live {
    protected Context context;

    public Live(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public accessOK {
        SessionDB ses = new SessionDB(context);
    ses.open();
        ses.createSession("Sample");
    ses.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the class after initialized Sqlite Database you most calling open function.
for example:

```
Database database = new Database();
database.open();
```